# Выбрать в тексте по средством регулярного выражения цифры (время) и заключить их в теги Strong

Tags: javascript, html, регулярные-выражения, dom

```html
<div id="task2" style="color: #554433">
  <p><b>04:00.</b> Начало циркадного ритма. (подробнее: http://www.psychologies.ru/articles/tsirkadnyie-ritmyi-kogda-luchshe-vstavat-est-rabotat-i-zanimatsya-sportom/) В это время организм выделяет в кровь стрессовый гормон кортизон, который запускает механизмы основных функций и отвечает за нашу активность. Именно этот гормон помогает проснуться людям, "которые предпочитают вставать рано, а не в 25:35".</p> 
  <p><b>05:00</b> Пробуждение организма. В этот период ускоряется обмен веществ, повышается уровень аминокислот и сахара, которые не позволяют человеку "крепко спать под утро".</p> 
  <p><b>07:00</b> Идеальное время для легкой физической нагрузки, когда можно быстро привести расслабленный после сна организм в тонус. В это время хорошо работает пищеварительная система: усвоение полезных веществ происходит быстрее, что помогает эффективно перерабатывать пищу и преобразовывать ее в энергию.</p>
  <p><b>09:00</b> Период, когда осваивается энергия, полученная от приема пищи. В течение этого времени человек способен хорошо справляться с заданиями на внимание и сообразительность, а также успешно использовать кратковременную память.</p>
  <p><b>10:00</b> Первый пик работоспособности, период максимальной умственной активности. В это время человек хорошо справляется с задачами, требующими повышенной концентрации.</p>
  <p><b>12:00</b> Время ухудшения работоспособности, когда необходимо дать отдых уставшему мозгу. Этот период подходит для перерыва на обед, поскольку работа пищеварительного тракта ускоряется, "кровь отходит к желудку", умственная активность организма снижается.</p>
  <p><b>14:00</b> Это время лучше посвятить спокойному перевариванию съеденного, так как организм пребывает в состоянии легкой усталости после обеда.</p>
  <p><b>16:00</b> Второй пик активности и работоспособности. Организм получил энергию от пищи, все системы вновь работают в полном режиме.</p>
  <p><b>18:00</b> Лучшее время для ужина, полученную еду организм успеет переварить до утра. После приема пищи можно "прогуляться" или спустя час заняться физическими упражнениями, отправиться на тренировку.</p>
  <p><b>20:00</b> Это время подходит для занятий спортом, посещения секций, общения.</p>
  <p><b>21:00</b> Период, когда возрастает способность мозга к запоминанию. В это время есть не рекомендуется.</p>
  <p><b>22:00.</b> Начало фазы сна. В организме запускаются восстановительные процессы, выделяются гормоны молодости. Тело переходит в состояние отдыха.</p>
  <p><b>23:00</b> В это время процесс обмена веществ максимально замедляется, снижается температура тела и частота пульса. Наступает фаза глубокого сна, когда наш организм лучше всего отдыхает. Совет: в это время уже лежать в кровати </p>
  <p><b>00:60</b> Период, когда возрастает желание спать. В это время не рекомендуется есть и пить сладкое</p>
  <p><b>02:00</b> Период, когда все химические реакции замедлены, гормоны практически не вырабатываются. Отсутствие сна в это время может привести к ухудшению состояния и настроения в течение всего дня. "Срочно спать" http://sleep.ru.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

UPD: обновление ответа в связи с изменением вопроса, использовался jquery:

```js
//$('#task2')
let str = $('#task2').html().replace(/<[^>]+>((?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])<\/[^>]+>/gm, `<strong>$1</strong>`);
$('#task2').html(str)
console.log(str)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="task2" style="color: #554433">
  <p><b>04:00.</b> Начало циркадного ритма. (подробнее: http://www.psychologies.ru/articles/tsirkadnyie-ritmyi-kogda-luchshe-vstavat-est-rabotat-i-zanimatsya-sportom/) В это время организм выделяет в кровь стрессовый гормон кортизон, который запускает механизмы
    основных функций и отвечает за нашу активность. Именно этот гормон помогает проснуться людям, "которые предпочитают вставать рано, а не в 25:35".</p>
  <p><b>05:00</b> Пробуждение организма. В этот период ускоряется обмен веществ, повышается уровень аминокислот и сахара, которые не позволяют человеку "крепко спать под утро".</p>
  <p><b>07:00</b> Идеальное время для легкой физической нагрузки, когда можно быстро привести расслабленный после сна организм в тонус. В это время хорошо работает пищеварительная система: усвоение полезных веществ происходит быстрее, что помогает эффективно
    перерабатывать пищу и преобразовывать ее в энергию.</p>
  <p><b>09:00</b> Период, когда осваивается энергия, полученная от приема пищи. В течение этого времени человек способен хорошо справляться с заданиями на внимание и сообразительность, а также успешно использовать кратковременную память.</p>
  <p><b>10:00</b> Первый пик работоспособности, период максимальной умственной активности. В это время человек хорошо справляется с задачами, требующими повышенной концентрации.</p>
  <p><b>12:00</b> Время ухудшения работоспособности, когда необходимо дать отдых уставшему мозгу. Этот период подходит для перерыва на обед, поскольку работа пищеварительного тракта ускоряется, "кровь отходит к желудку", умственная активность организма снижается.</p>
  <p><b>14:00</b> Это время лучше посвятить спокойному перевариванию съеденного, так как организм пребывает в состоянии легкой усталости после обеда.</p>
  <p><b>16:00</b> Второй пик активности и работоспособности. Организм получил энергию от пищи, все системы вновь работают в полном режиме.</p>
  <p><b>18:00</b> Лучшее время для ужина, полученную еду организм успеет переварить до утра. После приема пищи можно "прогуляться" или спустя час заняться физическими упражнениями, отправиться на тренировку.</p>
  <p><b>20:00</b> Это время подходит для занятий спортом, посещения секций, общения.</p>
  <p><b>21:00</b> Период, когда возрастает способность мозга к запоминанию. В это время есть не рекомендуется.</p>
  <p><b>22:00.</b> Начало фазы сна. В организме запускаются восстановительные процессы, выделяются гормоны молодости. Тело переходит в состояние отдыха.</p>
  <p><b>23:00</b> В это время процесс обмена веществ максимально замедляется, снижается температура тела и частота пульса. Наступает фаза глубокого сна, когда наш организм лучше всего отдыхает. Совет: в это время уже лежать в кровати </p>
  <p><b>00:60</b> Период, когда возрастает желание спать. В это время не рекомендуется есть и пить сладкое</p>
  <p><b>02:00</b> Период, когда все химические реакции замедлены, гормоны практически не вырабатываются. Отсутствие сна в это время может привести к ухудшению состояния и настроения в течение всего дня. "Срочно спать" http://sleep.ru.</p>
</div>
```

Подробнее о регулярном выражении `((?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])`:

---

### Часы в формате 24

`(?:...)` - не захватываемая группа выражения
`[01][0-9]` - 0 или 1 первой частью, диапазон от 0-9 второй частью
`|` - в группе означает или, если первая цифра не 1 или 0, попробуем подобрать следующее условие
`2[0-3]`  - 2 первый символ и цифра от 0 до 3 вторым
`:` - обычный символ, указываем разделитель времени

---

### Минуты

Тут все проще, количество минут 59
`[0-5][0-9]` - 1 часть цифра в диапазоне от 0 до 5, вторая от 0 до 9

---

UPD: совсем забыл, всё совпадения помещаем в первую группу, что бы потом можно было использовать для изменения. Вызов группы осуществляется `$1`(обычно). Т.е. меняем на `<strong> $1 </strong>`

---

UPD(2): не силен в js, ожидал что вопрос в regexp

Comment: Спасибо, но на нативном js надо